# Add Blazor support to existing ASP .NET Core 2.1 MVC application

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, blazor

I was looking at the Microsoft's new Blazor framework. It looks hugely impressive and would really help developers like me that has most of my Background in Desktop. Most of the Examples and tutorials that i see tells you how to start from scratch. I already have an existing .net core(2.1) MVC project with Ef core , Identity a that i wanted to add Blazor support.  And i couldn't figure out how to do it. so hereby hoping someone here Might have faced similar issue and figured it or some one more knowledgeable may help me 
Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I wrote a blogpost about that: http://flores.eken.nl/mixing-blazor-and-mvc-pages-in-one-app/

Basically:

In the startup.cs of your site, change the app.UseBlazor() statement to:

`app.Map("/bzr", child => { child.UseBlazor<Blazor.Program>(); });`

And in the index.html in the wwwroot, alter the base href to:

`<base href="/bzr/" />`

Comment: Off-topic: why does your blog page start with a huge full-page image of a Stack Trace? Very confusing, or if intended to be funny, IMO not at all funny...

Comment: Thank you !! Even though it was not exactly what i was looking for I Actually learned a lot . I wanted to try and use Blazor as a like for like replacement for JS ie instead of using JS in my  scripts in my CSHTML page i wanted to try and use Blazor.  In the end i ended up going with React . But still learned something new so thank you :)